# -Duser.language=zh doesn't work in ecilpse JUNO

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-juno

I use ubuntu 12.04 64 bits with locale en_US.UTF-8 (I muse use english locale). The default key binding content assist in ecilpse is ctrl+spacebar. I want to change it to alt+/ because ctrl+spacebar is used to activate the chinese input method.

In previous eclipse version, I add "-Duser.language=zh" in the bottom of eclipse.ini, and ecilpse will change the content assist key shortcuts to alt+/. However, in the latest eclipse (4.2 juno), it takes no effects.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using -Duser.language=zh in eclipse.ini, just before the --launcher argument add the following  options:

```
-nl
zh_CN
```

Comment: Thanks. These two ways all work after I remove .metadata folder under my workspace. This is my ecilpse.ini.
`code`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-nl
zh_TW
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
`code`